# should be initialized in the member initialization list в c++

Tags: c++

`students.h`:

```
#pragma once

struct Students
{
        std::string name;
        int raiting;
};
```

`qwer.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "students.h"

int main()
{
        Students Nick;
        Nick.raiting = 1;
        std::cout << Nick.raiting << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Выдает предупреждение. Что оно означает?:

```
students.h: In constructor ‘Students::Students()’:
students.h:3:8: warning: ‘Students::name’ should be initialized in the member initialization list [-Weffc++]
    3 | struct Students
      |        ^~~~~~~~
students.h:3:8: warning: ‘Students::raiting’ should be initialized in the member initialization list [-Weffc++]
qwer.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
qwer.cpp:6:11: note: synthesized method ‘Students::Students()’ first required here
    6 |  Students Nick;
      |           ^~~~
```

Comment: Чем компилируете? VС++ ничего такого не пишет, gcc вроде тоже - https://ideone.com/2AEG6E

Comment: устаревший компилятор

Comment: @Harry g++ -Wall -Weffc++ -Wextra -Wsign-conversion -g3 -O0 -std=c++17 qwer.cpp     -o main

Comment: @AlexGlebe То есть на это можно не обращать внимание ?

Comment: компилятор вроде бы свежий, но я никогда не использую `-Weffc++` - он дурь пишет иногда

Comment: См.: [Understanding -Weffc++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11496942).

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы закрыть эти предупреждения можно поставить конструктор по-умолчанию.

```
struct Students
{
    std::string name { } ;
    int raiting { } ;
};
```

Тогда переменнаю `raiting` - всегда будет инициализирована нулём. Против забывчивых. А переменная `name` всегда **уже** будет инициализирована, вот это лажа компилятора (*лишнее советует*).